# What is headless authentication?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am solving quizzes on a cloud associate course and came across the term "headless authentication", I search over the internet but didn't get a clear answer. here is the question, can anyone clear my point?

> You are planning on using the Azure container registry service. You want to ensure that your application or service can use it for headless authentication. You also want to allow role-based access to the registry. You decide to perform an individual login to the registry. Would this fulfil the requirement?

Comment: That means no interactive logon (think popping up a browser window). Which really means whatever needs to access your container registry can do so without user interaction. It's not a very well-chosen term but it is what it is.

Comment: Here's a reference describing it as "unattended" - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-authentication